# Can I use PCR buffer instead of cDNA synthesis buffer?

Tags: molecular-biology

I am using Fermentase First strand cDNA synthesis kit but its buffer is over. I need to work today but I have not access to any sorce currently. I have PCR buffer in the lab. Can I use PCR buffer instead of cDNA synthesis buffer? What are your other suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This page](http://www.enzymatics.com/product_p7040-l.htm) has the recipe for 10X M-MuLV RT buffer:

- 500 mM Tris-HCl
- 750 mM KCl
- 30 mM MgCl2
- 100 mM DTT
- pH 8.3

If you have the basic reagents, I suggest making that.